# How can I get both dates from daterange picker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date-range, daterangepicker

I have an html page which uses the simple DateRange input from: [BeatPicker/demos](http://act1gmr.github.io/BeatPicker/demos.html)
I can get the StartDate from the input, but I can't seem to get the EndDate.  Both dates are entered using the single input element.

```
<input type="text" id="demo" data-beatpicker="true" data-beatpicker-position="['*','*']" data-beatpicker-range="true"/>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
alert(demo.value);  // gives Start Date
alert(demo.startDate);  // gives Start Date

// below show undefined
//var x = myDatePicker.getSelectedEndDate;
//var x = document.getElementById("demo").getSelectedEndDate.value];
//alert(x);
}
</script>
```

[BeatPicker Documentation](http://act1gmr.github.io/BeatPicker/docs.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have not selected a date, then your function will not work as expected.

I would use the `select` event of the date picker to actually get the values.

According to the BeatPicker documentation, the methods to get start date and end date are `getSelectedStartDate` and `getSelectedEndDate`. Since you have used the declarative syntax, you can also give your date picker an `id` via `data-beatpicker-id="myPicker"`.  If you do that, you can reference the date picker via that id.

Update your element declaration:

```
<input data-beatpicker-id="myPicker" type="text" id="demo" data-beatpicker="true" data-beatpicker-position="['*','*']" data-beatpicker-range="true" />
```

Try changing your function to use those methods:

```
function myFunction(){
  var startDt = myPicker.getSelectedStartDate();
  var endDt = myPicker.getSelectedEndDate();

  console.log(startDt, endDt);
}
```

At the bottom of the demos page, you can see an example of hooking into the data picker events.  Using the `select` or `change` event is a better idea than the function called by a button:

```
    var statusGenerator = function (text) {
        var statusElem = $(".status");
        var child = $("<span></span>").text(text);
        statusElem.append(child);
    };

    myDatePicker.on("select", function (data) {
        myFunction();
        statusGenerator(data.string + " selected")
    });

    myDatePicker.on("change", function (data) {
        myFunction();
        statusGenerator("Date picker changed current date: "+data.string);
    });
```

Comment: Thank You so much!   It works perfect.  I tried using getSelectedEndDate() but I didn't know how to use it as a "function" and I got an error because of the "()" at the end.  Thanks for showing me how that works.  I hope this helps others.